# PCA Analysis in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, pca, apache-spark-ml

Looking at http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-dimensionality-reduction.html. The examples seem to only contain Java and Scala.

Does Spark MLlib support PCA analysis for Python? If so please point me to an example. If not, how to combine Spark with scikit-learn?

Comment: Just to add that a solution for this issue is in progress. Check the progress at [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6227) and [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/7963/files).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### Spark >= 1.5.0

Although PySpark 1.5 introduces distributed data structures (`pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed`) it looks like API is rather limited and there is no implementation of the `computePrincipalComponents` method.

It is possible to use either `from pyspark.ml.feature.PCA` or `pyspark.mllib.feature.PCA` though. In the first case an expected input is a data frame with vector column:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import PCA as PCAml
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors  # Pre 2.0 pyspark.mllib.linalg

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
   (Vectors.dense([1, 2, 0]),),
   (Vectors.dense([2, 0, 1]),),
   (Vectors.dense([0, 1, 0]),)], ("features", ))

pca = PCAml(k=2, inputCol="features", outputCol="pca")
model = pca.fit(df)
transformed = model.transform(df)
```

In Spark 2.0 or later you should use `pyspark.ml.linalg.Vector` in place of `pyspark.mllib.linalg.Vector`.

For `mllib` version you'll need a `RDD` of `Vector`:

```
from pyspark.mllib.feature import PCA as PCAmllib

rdd = sc.parallelize([
    Vectors.dense([1, 2, 0]),
    Vectors.dense([2, 0, 1]),
    Vectors.dense([0, 1, 0])])

model = PCAmllib(2).fit(rdd)
transformed = model.transform(rdd)
```

#### Spark < 1.5.0

PySpark <= 1.4.1 doesn't support distributed data structures yet so there is no built-in method to compute PCA. If input matrix is relatively thin you can compute covariance matrix in a distributed manner, collect the results and perform eigendecomposition locally on a driver.

Order of operations is more or less like the one bellow. Distributed steps are followed by a name of the operation, local by "*" and optional method.

1. Create `RDD[Vector]`  where each element is a single row from an input matrix. You can use `numpy.ndarray` for each row (`prallelize`)
2. Compute column-wise statistics (`reduce`)
3. Use results from 2. to center the matrix (`map`)
4. Compute outer product for each row (`map outer`)
5. Sum results to obtain covariance matrix (`reduce +`)
6. Collect and compute eigendecomposition * (`numpy.linalg.eigh`)
7. Choose top-n eigenvectors *
8. Project the data (`map`)

Regarding Sklearn. You can use NumPy (it is already in use in `Mllib`), SciPy, Scikit **locally** on a driver or a worker the same way as usual.

Comment: WHat about Spark > 2 ? 
Syntax seems to have changed

Comment: @MehdiLAMRANI it worked for me. I am using databricks

Comment: have a question for @zero323 How do I apply to the actual data frame? Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: I still haven't understood if the PCA library automatically standardazies the data before performing PCA. Anyone knows?