# How to use PCA from pyspark.ml.feature?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pca

I need to apply PCA to a CSV. Looking for examples I have [seen one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774311/pca-analysis-in-pyspark) as an answer to a question on this site. I have tried to follow it but it gives me an error. If someone could help me?
My code is this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.feature import PCA as PCAml

spark = SparkSession.Builder().appName("read_csv").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    dfX = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema",True).option("header",True).load("inmune_X.csv")
                    
    dfX=dfX.drop('_c0')
                 
    assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=dfX.columns,outputCol="atributos")
    dd = assembler.transform(dfX)
    dd.select("atributos").show(5)
        
    pca = PCAml(k=4, inputCol="atributos", outputCol="pca")
    model = pca.fit(assembler)
    transformed = model.transform(assembler)
    transformed.show(5)
```

This is the error message:

> File "D:\UGR\Investigación\Cosas de Reinaldo\mis
> script\Seleccion_caracteristicas\pca_rowmatrix_example.py", line 65,
> in 
> model = pca.fit(assembler)
>
> File "C:\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\base.py", line
> 129, in fit
> return self._fit(dataset)
>
> File "C:\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py",
> line 321, in _fit
> java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
>
> File "C:\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py",
> line 318, in _fit_java
> return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
>
> AttributeError: 'VectorAssembler' object has no attribute '_jdf'

Comment: You are passing the `VectorAssembler` object to `pca.fit()`. You should be passing the transformed dataset instead: `pca.fit(dd)`.

Comment: You're right. I no longer have the error. But now I would like to know how I interpret the results